# how to run multiple elastic search (2.2) nodes as processes on the same server

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

i was wondering if you help me out here;
am trying to run multiple elasticsearch processes on the same (CentOS) server, but i have been un-successful so far.
and i have not enabled the service wrapper. and Elasticsearch has been installed using the .rpm package

the requirements are:

1. every instance belongs to a different cluster (cluster.name)
2. every instance uses a different port, 9201, 9202, 9203, etc.
3. every instance should be parameterised with different ES_HEAP_SIZE

the `elasticsearch.yml` file is attached where all parameters are described.

and the questions are:

1. how to set a different configuration file per instance when `Des.config` seems to be deprecated in 2.2
2. how to set a custom ES_HEAP_SIZE (-Xmx=24G -Xms=24G) when

*# bin/elasticsearch -Des.config=config/IP-spotlight.RRv4/elasticsearch.yml  [2016-02-14 19:44:02,858][INFO ][bootstrap                ] es.config is no longer supported. elasticsearch.yml must be placed in the config directory and cannot be renamed.*

please help ..

Comment: Why not trying docker solution? It would be much simpler to scale the number of instances. There is a docker image for es:https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming questions only. From the SO help pages: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two solutions:

1. download `elasticsearch` archive from the site and run it from different paths with different configs. You can monitor each running instance with a method like `supervisor`. The main page for Elasticsearch downloads  is [here](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch)
2. run each instance inside a `docker` container. This is the right way to do, because it is easier to deploy and manage. You can find a Elasticsearch docker image [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/)